# Using IKVM to convert a JAR (Flying Saucer - xhtmlrenderer)

Tags: java, .net, ikvm, flying-saucer

I wanted to use the Flying Saucer Java API in .NET so I tried to use [IKVM](http://ikvm.net) to convert the [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) library:

```
ikvmc core-renderer.jar
```

For some reason, IKVMC gave me an exe `core-renderer.exe` so I renamed it to `core-renderer.dll`, added to my assemblies and hacked away

```
using java.io;
using java.lang;
using com.lowagie.text;
using org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf;

namespace flying_saucer
{
    class FlyingSaucerApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This works
            DocumentException dummy = new DocumentException();

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();


            // For some reason, this raises NoClassDefFoundError                
            renderer.setDocument(File("hello.xhtml").toURI().toURL().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is giving `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException`. I realized `DocumentException` is something `ITextRender()` may throw, but I've already included `com.lowagie.text`, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that for this particular situation, I needed to render both Flying Saucer and iText (a dependency of Flying Saucer) and have the Flying Saucer assembly reference to its dependency:

```
ikvmc -target:library itext.jar
ikvmc -target:library -reference:itext.dll core-renderer.jar
```

(For newbies: If you didn't read any documentation and are just trying the commands, you also need to make sure the DLL files accompanying IKVMC is also present -- the easiest way to do this is to dump all the IKVMC files beside your iText JAR files)

Comment: tried your commands but it says core-renderer.dll is an unknown filetype

Comment: Obviously, I made that answer in a haste :p I changed it and again obviously, the arguments should be `jar` files lol

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've included `IKVM.AWT.WinForms.dll`, `IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary.dll`, `IKVM.Runtime.dll` and `IKVM.Runtime.JNI.dll` assemblies into your project. Also to avoid generating an executable and then renaming it you could specify the `-target:library` switch when compiling.

Comment: Thanks for the note for `-target:library`. It felt cleaner than having to rename the exe file. Still getting the mentioned error though :\